# Not able to read annotation property inside Aspect when writing pointcut in a method

Tags: kotlin, spring-aop, aspect, pointcut

I have a custom annotation as

```
annotation class MyHandler(val value:String)
```

I wrote an aspect for functions using this annotation, also reading the value within the annotation for my processing.

```
    @Around("@annotation(myHandler)")
    fun handleExceptions(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint, myHandler: MyHandler) {
        println(myHandler.value) //this works
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed()
        } catch (e: Exception){
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly fine.

I then tried to move the pointcut definition to a separate function as below and this is where I am running into issues.

```
    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.example.demo.MyHandler)")
    fun myHandlerFunc() {}
    
    @Around(value = "myHandlerFunc()")
    fun handleExceptions(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint, myHandler: MyHandler) {
        println(myHandler.value) //this works
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed()
        } catch (e: Exception){
        }
    }
```

Error being -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut.
```

Any way I could still have access to the annotation properties, while having the pointcut definition in a separate method?

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work after some trial and error

```
    @Pointcut("@annotation(myHandler)")
    fun myHandlerFunc(myHandler: MyHandler) {}

    @Around(value = "myHandlerFunc(myHandler)")
    fun handleExceptions(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint, myHandler: MyHandler) {
        println(myHandler.value)
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed()
        } catch (e: Exception){
        }
    }
```

Is there a better or cleaner way to accomplish this?

Comment: This is the correct, canonical Spring AOP or AspectJ solution. It is both elegant and type-safe, no reflection involved. What is it that you do not like about it? If you want to streamline your code and the pointcut is only used by a single advice, you may want to inline instead of reference it, i.e. get rid of `@Pointcut` and use `@Around("@annotation(myHandler)")`. P.S.: Instead of trial and error, reading a [manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params) would have been an alternative. 

Comment: @kriegaex Thank you for validating this. Nothing I do not like as such, just making sure I'm using it right.